# I need to find a proper data structure

Tags: java, algorithm

I am not sure what data structure I should use to solve it,
I have a list of categories and list of values that are associated to them as following:

```
Categories           Values 
Smart             **person1**,person2
Handsome          person3,person6,**person1**
Hard-Working      person7,person9
```

For example, person1 is Smart and Handsome because he is in both Handsome and Smart categories. (a value(person) can be in many categories) and person2 is Smart but is not Handsome.

person object has name,age and gender for example person 1 is

```
John 43 Male
```

I am wondering how I can design it, **I was thinking of a two-dimention array** but it is not a good idea as I would have some spare places

```
Cat1 v3,v6 Spare Spare
Cat2 v10 Spare Spare Spare
cat4 v6,v7,v8,v9
```

**I suppose the best is to have a list but** not sure how to find out which value is for which category or categories ( like V6 in above example that is associated to both cat1 and cat4)

```
 V3 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10
```

Comment: what are v3 and Spare in the example above?  Are the they Person?

Comment: is this homework? If so please tag it as such

Comment: @hvgotcodes, no its not but I am newbie, and trying to learn more thats why I asked about the differences otherwise I would just solve the problem rather than learning.

Comment: @hvgotcodes, you are right its data structure question, I am wondering which data structure would suit this issue most, the questions that I need to solve is that which persons are associated to each category?(give categories to get persons) or  which person is associated to which category? (give person and get the list of categories that he is associated to) number of persons that are associated to each category , ….

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like

`Map<Category, List<Person>>`

Since `Map` should provide O(1) access, you want your key to be what you use to look up the most (Category in your case, from what I gather).  So if you have

`Map<Category, List<Person>> categoryLookup = new HashMap<Category, ArrayList<Person>>();`

you can do

`List<Person> values = myCategoryLookup.get(someCategory);`

and then iterate over the values.  References to the same value can be in multiple lists -- that is not a problem.

For Yameo below, if you want to get categories for a person, you can either

1. have `Person` maintain a list of its categories
2. "reverse" the datastructure above; i.e. also maintain a `Map<Person, List<Category>>`

The alternative to these solutions is to set the relationships in the `Category` and `Person` classes themselves.  For example, `Person` would have a `List<Category>` as one of its class properties, and similarly `Category` would have a `List<Person>` as one of its class properties.  But I get the sense this is more a data-structures question.   This what you would probably do if you had a database that contains the actual data and were going to use an ORM tool to map the data to Java classes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you have any example of it?

Comment: @Sirinvar Reddy Thatiparthy, what do you mean by set I have never heard of

Comment: Yes Yarneo is right, I should have a flexible data structure , because I may need to know, for example who is in most of categories? who is not in any or in just one category?

Comment: @hvgotcodes thanks for your response, but would you give me more example or if you know of a tutorial please share it with me, should I use HashMap or Map? and how to find number of occurrence of a value in categories ?

Comment: @Eme You need to do some reading.  Map is an interface and HashMap is a type of Map...

Comment: to get the number of people for a category, you would simply get the list and then use the `size` method....

Comment: @hvgotcodes, that is another example of the issue, Vx mean different values that will be in categories, and spare means spare part of memory that I may occupy if I use 2dimension array.

Answer (score 1):

In a database you would use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). See also [many to many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29). Depending on what you need, you could use an `enum` for the categories and a `MultiMap<Person, Category>` for the storage.

Comment: I suppose many to many is not a good idea as we have to avoid these type of relationships in database.

Comment: So you want this data to be stored in a database? You relationship is many to many, so you need an appropriate way to store it. In a database this is a junction table. Otherwise your data would not be normalized (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: I see I need to think about that I will assess the normalisation thanks